# How can I wrap every request with RestClient to use :verify_ssl => false?

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I'm trying

```
RestClient.add_before_execution_proc do |req, params|
  req(:verify_ssl => false)
end
```

It isn't working.

How can I wrap every request with RestClient to use :verify_ssl => false?

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: I instead made a script to copy our corporate cert to the directory that Ruby needs. Maybe I can make a shareable version of that with no corporate data and link it here. @alberge had a good point in saying 'if you're setting `verify_ssl: false` you might as well not be using https at all.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `params` instead of `req`. Those params will be passed to `RestClient.execute`, which is the entry point for all requests.

```
RestClient.add_before_execution_proc do |req, params|
  params[:verify_ssl] = false
end
```

Comment: That's not gonna work with the latest (2.0.2) for 2 reasons: 1. [the code that actually sets the ssl verify mode in the http connection object](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/6beead019b9971f9576e78f78e140a377b3d6d3d/lib/restclient/request.rb#L660) is executed *before* the `before_execution_proc`s are invoked; 2. the value of the verify mode is taken from `@ssl_opts` (see [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/6beead019b9971f9576e78f78e140a377b3d6d3d/lib/restclient/request.rb#L165)), which is only set in the constructor.

Comment: @alb-i986 I've added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62093035/6890912) that patches the constructor instead then.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider creating a simple class to encapsulate your needs and execute a get/post/... rest without `verify_ssl`

(check https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/request.rb#L160)

Answer (score 1):

I'd write my own helper wrapper for the RestClient calls rather than modifying global state, since global changes make it hard for someone reading your code to understand what's happening.

For example:

```
def insecure_restclient_get(url, headers={}, &block)
  RestClient::Request.execute(verify_ssl: false, method: :get, url: url, headers: headers, &block)
end

def insecure_restclient_post(url, payload, headers={}, &block)
  RestClient::Request.execute(verify_ssl: false, method: :post, url: url, payload: payload, headers: headers, &block)
end
```

Also note that if you're setting `verify_ssl: false` you might as well not be using https at all.

Answer (score 0):

In response to @alb-i986's comment for @AlexandreAngelim's answer, I've written the follow monkey patch that wraps the constructor of `RestClient::Request` class instead so it would work with the latest `RestClient`:

```
module RestClient
    class Request
        orig_initialize = instance_method(:initialize)

        define_method(:initialize) do |args|
            args[:verify_ssl] = false
            orig_initialize.bind(self).(args)
        end
    end
end
```